# Unable To get Selected text on Enter key press from list box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying for smart search on my web page, so in my search on Click event I am getting Text which is selected in same textarea and but when I try with On keypress I'm unable to do find text of selected item. I am using jquery1.4.2 and tried  option:select but still fail to do so... 
My Code for click

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_smartSearch').keyup(function(e) {
    var str = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_smartSearch');
    //alert("hi");

    if (str.value.length >= 2) {

      if (e.keyCode != 40 && e.keyCode != 38 && e.keyCode != 13) {
        var str1 = str.value;
        var str2 = str1.replace(' ', '+')
        var url = "../SiteCache/90D/SmartGetQuoteData.aspx?Type=EQ&text=" + str2;

        $("#ajax_response_smart").load(url);

      }

      $("#ajax_response_smart").show();
      $('#listEQ li').live('click', function() {        
        var selected = $(this).text();              
        $("#ajax_response_smart").remove(); 
        if (selected != "") {
          var scripcode = selected.split("|");
          document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_smartSearch').value = scripcode[0];
          document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnCode').value = scripcode[2];                    
        }
      });

      var $listItems = $('#listEQ li');
      var key = e.keyCode,
      $selected = $listItems.filter('.ui-state-hover'),
            $current;

      if (key != 40 && key != 38 && key != 13)
      { return; }
      else {
        $listItems.removeClass('ui-state-hover');
      }


      if (key == 40) // Down key
      {
        if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child')) {
          $current = $listItems.eq(0);
        }
        else {

          $current = $selected.next();
        }
      }
      else if (key == 38) // Up key
      {
        if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':first-child')) {
          $current = $listItems.last();
        }
        else {
          $current = $selected.prev();
        }
      }
      else if (key == 13) {
      }
    }
    else {
      $("#ajax_response_smart").hide();
    }
    if (typeof $current != "undefined") {
      $current.addClass('ui-state-hover');
    }
  });
  $("#ajax_response_smart").mouseover(function() {
    var $listItems1 = $('#listEQ li');
    $selected1 = $listItems1.filter('.ui-state-hover');
    $(this).find("#listEQ li").mouseover(function() {
      ($selected1).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
      $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
    });
    $(this).find("#listEQ li").mouseout(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
    });
  });
});
```

Please Suggest and Thanks in advance

Comment: hey i got the answer i called the keypress event on my textbox in aspx page and from there i came on the currently paosted js page then on keypress event i got value.i.e not able to use keyup event to detect enter

Answer (score 0):

hey i got my the answer i called the keypress event on my textbox in aspx page and from there i came on the currently paosted js page then on keypress event i got value.i.e not able to use keyup event to detect enter